# Monte Carlo simulation of N dice

Tags: python, montecarlo

I'm doing this assignment:

> You are tossing `N` dice. Write a program in Python that computes the probability that the sum is larger than `3N/2` and smaller than `9N/2`.

I supposed that I have only 3 dice because it's a little bit complicated to make with `N` dice and I've tried something but I don't understand how to find the probability that the `9N/2 > sum > 3N/2`

```
import random
num_throws = 20  # NT
roll_log = [0] * 12  # Generate list for dice roll tallies

for i in range(num_throws):
    # Random integer between 1 and 6 inclusive for each dice
    dice_1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    dice_2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    dice_3 = random.randint(1, 6)

    # Sum the random dice and increment the tally for that particular roll total
    roll_sum = dice_1 + dice_2
    roll_log[roll_sum-1] += 1  # minus 1 because Python is 0-indexed

    for i, tally in enumerate(roll_log):
        roll_prob = float(tally) / num_throws  # Experimental probability of roll
        roll = i + 1  # Since Python lists are 0-indexed
        print('{}: {}/{} = {}'.format(roll, tally, num_throws, roll_prob))
        n = 5
        m = 10

rolls_between = roll_log[n:m-1]  
sum_rolls_between = sum(rolls_between)  
prob_between = float(sum_rolls_between) / num_throws
```

Comment: Aren't statistical calculations in combination with the pseudo-random method the ingredients for a terrible homework-assignment..? ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix yeah, but what can I do?

Comment: The assigments wording is already confusing: _'What is the probability in Python'_ It should be: _'Write a program in Python that calculates the probability of ..according to...'_

Comment: @iLuvLogix teacher's fault, I've edited the question now.

Comment: have a look here https://sciencing.com/calculate-dice-probabilities-5858157.html

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Is your `prob_between` wrong?

Comment: @BlackBear I need to compute the probability that the sum is larger than 3N/2 and smaller than 9N/2

Comment: By using "only 3 dice" you made the problem more complicated than it needs to be. The program should be as simple as: (1) initialize sum with 0; (2) N times, choose a random number from 1 to 6 and add it to the sum; (3) compare the sum to 3N/2 and to 9N/2; (4) repeat steps 1-3 many times and count how often the sum was larger than 3N/2 and smaller than 9N/2

Comment: Maybe you should to this with real dice on paper first to get a feel for what the program should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the first answer... no idea if correct...
Just fixed the obvious errors...

```
import random                                                                                       

N = 3                                                                                               
NUM_ROLLS = 10000                                                                                   
UPPER_BOUND = 9 * N / 2                                                                             
LOWER_BOUND = 3 * N / 2                                                                             

counter = 0                                                                                         
for _ in range(NUM_ROLLS):                                                                          
  s = sum([random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(N)])                                                 
  if s < UPPER_BOUND and s > LOWER_BOUND:                                                           
    counter += 1                                                                                    

prob = 1.0 * counter / NUM_ROLLS                                                                    
print "Upper Bound = ", UPPER_BOUND                                                                 
print "Lower Bound = ", LOWER_BOUND                                                                 
print prob
```

Comment: NB: I am using Python 2.7.16

Comment: By the way, the higher the number of dices, the more the probability gets to 1